# Why is my PNG resolution with Ghostscript not what I specified?

Tags: resolution, tesseract, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I am using the following command in Ghostscript:

```
gs -dSAFER -sDEVICE=png16m -dDOINTERPOLATE -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dNumRenderingThreads=8 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=612 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=792 -r600 -o ./test_gs/output_%d.png -c 30000000 setvmthreshold -f ./test_gs/input.pdf
```

input.pdf is an 8.5''x11'' pdf which looks crisp and clear. The resulting PNG's that gs produces don't look nearly as good, but are mostly acceptable. A problem I just noticed though is that, even though I'm specifying a 600 resolution ("-r600"), ImageMagick's `identify` is reporting back a resolution of only 236.22:

```
  Geometry: 5100x6600+0+0
  Resolution: 236.22x236.22
  Print size: 21.59x27.9401
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Type: GrayscaleAlpha
  Base type: GrayscaleAlpha
```

Why is this? And how can I fix it so that the dpi is higher (at least 300) for use with Tesseract?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091655/ghostscript-pdf-to-png-output-is-always-595x842-a4?

Comment: I don't see how these are the same. I'm getting an odd resolution given my settings - that question is asking about output size.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Ghostscript are you using ? Where we can find a copy of the PDF to examine ?

Comment: copy: http://www.ilsmac.com/uploads/xI/0L/xI0Lhh_WWolV5iHt91w2yw/illinois_master_smac_jan_22_2014.pdf, version: 8.71

Comment: I tried the current version of Ghostscript (9.14) using your command line and the resulting image for page 1 was 5100x6600 pixels. Given that the original media size is 8.5x11 inches that means there are 5100/8.5 66100/11 pixels per inch, or 600x600 dpi. Note that ImageMagick is giving you a resolution in pixels per *centimetre*. Multiplying by 2.54 gives pixels per inch, and is also 600 (236.22*2.54 = 599.998). So I don't see a problem with the resolution of the output.

Comment: ohhhh, thank you for pointing out the cm translation. that makes sense. I appreciate you checking on this Ken.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried it using a newer version like you did. Did it come out looking ... good? I find that the command I've been using appears a bit faded and not nearly as good as the original. Did you find the same?

Comment: Looks fine to me, but I don't know what you find objectionable, exactly.

Answer (score -1):

There's an old Chinese proverb:

> 任何人谁可以阅读，有一个明显的优势。
>
> *"These who can read have a very distinctive advantage."*

Your `identify` command does not give you `dpi`, it gives you `ppcm` (pixels per centimeter). And it even tells you so: just look at the line saying `Units: PixelsPerCentimeter`.

And in my book, 236.22 ppcm computes into 600 ppi easily (there are 2.54 Centimeters in 1 Inch):

```
bc <<< "scale=2;(236.22 * 2.54)"
599.99
```

So there is no need to fix your command, if you really want 600 ppi.

If you want 1200 ppi, use that value in your `gs` command instead...

Comment: This was noticed and commented by KenS almost a year ago.

Comment: @user592419: Sorry, didn't see that before. Also, looking at KenS' answer now, it seems it was a *month* ago, not a *year*.

Comment: @user592419: I'm confused now... KenS gave you an answer before you asked your question?!